# show follow line and tooltip on flutter chart

Tags: flutter, charts, linechart

I am new to the flutter and I am trying to draw a chart similar to below chart with a follow line and a tooltip using flutter chart package.

[desired chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu4I7.png)

I searched and found a GitHub issue that was useful. the solution was to create a custom CircleSymbolRenderer and override the paint function and draw the tooltip. it works individually but when I put it in my actual project the follow line and tooltip are not visible. here is the full code of my chart.

```
class ShoeDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String imageUrl, shoeName, shoeId, shoeSizeId,topMover;

  ShoeDetailPage({this.imageUrl, this.shoeName, this.shoeId, this.shoeSizeId,this.topMover});

  @override
  _ShoeDetailPageState createState() => _ShoeDetailPageState();
}

class _ShoeDetailPageState extends State<ShoeDetailPage> with AfterLayoutMixin {
  ShoeFullInfo bloc = new ShoeFullInfo();

  String _dateTime;
  String capital;
  DateTime selectedDate;

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer ${UserInfo.GetToken()}"
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil(width: 1080, height: 1920)..init(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: displayAppBarWithCentertitle("", blueColor, context),
        body: Container(
          height: ScreenUtil.instance.height,
          width: ScreenUtil.instance.width,
          color: backgroundColor,
          child: StreamBuilder<bool>(
              stream: bloc.loading,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data) {
                  return displayCircularProgressIndicater(context);
                }
                if(bloc.statusCode!=200){
                  return alertCode(bloc.statusCode);
                }
                if (!bloc.connection) {
                  return displayNoInternet();
                }

                return displayGraphContainer();
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

List<charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>> _createSampleData() {
    return [
      new charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>(
        id: 'US Sales',
        domainFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.time,
        measureFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: bloc.salesData,
        radiusPxFn: (a, b) => b == bloc.lastIndex ? 8 : 0,
        fillColorFn: (a, b) {
          return b == bloc.lastIndex
              ? charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.pinkAccent)
              : charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue);
        },

        patternColorFn: (a,b) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.red),
        colorFn: (a,b) {
          return b == bloc.lastIndex
              ? charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.pinkAccent.withOpacity(0.7))
              : charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue);
        },

      ),
    ];
  }

  Widget displayGraphContainer() {
    String amount;
    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: bloc.onChangeData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data) {
            return new Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 250,
            );
          }

          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 250,
            child: charts.TimeSeriesChart(
              _createSampleData(),
              animate: false,
              defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(
                includePoints: true,
                includeLine: true,
                roundEndCaps: true,
                stacked: true
              ),
              primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                renderSpec: new charts.NoneRenderSpec(),
              ),
              domainAxis: new charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
                tickProviderSpec: charts.DayTickProviderSpec(increments: [40]),
                tickFormatterSpec: new charts.AutoDateTimeTickFormatterSpec(
                  day: new charts.TimeFormatterSpec(
                    format: 'dd',transitionFormat: 'MMM-dd', noonFormat: 'EEE'
                  )
                )
              ),
              selectionModels: [
                new charts.SelectionModelConfig(
                  type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
                  changedListener: (charts.SelectionModel data) {
                    bloc.changeChartPoint(data.selectedDatum[0].index);
                  }
                )
              ],
              behaviors: [
                new charts.LinePointHighlighter(
                  symbolRenderer: (CustomCircleSymbolRenderer("3")),
                    showHorizontalFollowLine: charts.LinePointHighlighterFollowLineType.none,
                  showVerticalFollowLine: charts.LinePointHighlighterFollowLineType.nearest,
                  drawFollowLinesAcrossChart: true
                ),
                new charts.SelectNearest(
                  eventTrigger: charts.SelectionTrigger.tapAndDrag
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

and this is the custom CircleSymbolRendererClass

```
    class CustomCircleSymbolRenderer extends charts.CircleSymbolRenderer {
  String amount;

  CustomCircleSymbolRenderer(this.amount);
  @override
  void paint(charts.ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds, {List<int> dashPattern, chart_color.Color fillColor,charts.FillPatternType fillPattern, chart_color.Color strokeColor, double strokeWidthPx, String text}) {
    super.paint(canvas, bounds, dashPattern: dashPattern, fillColor: fillColor, strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);
    canvas.drawRect(
        Rectangle(bounds.left - 5, bounds.top - 30, bounds.width + 10, bounds.height + 10),
        fill: chart_color.Color.white
    );


    var textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = chart_color.Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 25;
    canvas.drawText(
        te.TextElement("1", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(),
        (bounds.top - 28).round()
    );
  }
}
```

does anyone know what possibly might have gone wrong?